# how to perform frequency convolution?

Tags: convolution, continuous-signals

much has been said about convolution of continuous time signals. But what about frequency convolution?

For instance, consider the function:

$$f(t) = \text{sinc}(t)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$$

I take the Fourier of f(t):

$$\mathscr{F}\Big\{f(t)\Big\} = \mathscr{F} \Big\{ \text{sinc}(t) \Big\}$$

$$F(\Omega) = \text{rect}(\Omega)$$

where: $$\text{rect}(\Omega) = \begin{cases}1 & |\Omega|< 1/2 \\ 0 &|\Omega| >1/2\end{cases}$$

Then perform convolution of $F(\Omega)$ with itself in the frequency domain:

$$G(\Omega) = F(\Omega) * F(\Omega)$$

$$G(\Omega) = \text{rect}(\Omega) * \text{rect}(\Omega)$$

$$G(\Omega) =  \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{rect}(u) ~\text{rect}(u-\Omega)~ du$$

[answer according to wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20y%28t%29%20%3D%20int%20-infinity%20to%20infinity%20rect%28T%29*rect%28T-t%29%20dT)

its a triangle between -1 and 1.

I would have thought that graphically you perform this convolution by sliding $\text{rect}(u-\Omega)$ across $\text{rect}(u)$ starting at $u=-1/2$ and ending at $u = 1/2 + 1 = 3/2$.  since the width of $\text{rect}(u-\Omega)$ is 1 in length.

but this contradicts the $\Omega$ range given by wolfram alpha of -1 to 1.

what gives?

Comment: i guess i'm wrong, you start convolution at $u=-1$ and end at $u=1$

Comment: I am confused about your use of $t = 1/2$ since you are in the frequency domain. If you meant $\Omega = 1/2$, wouldn't it be $\Omega = -1/2$ since $|\Omega|<1/2$?

Comment: I think, my mistake was thinking the right edge of $\text{rect}(u-\Omega)$ was u,  its actually u+1/2.  the center of $\text{rect}(u-\Omega)$ is u.

Comment: So whether it is frequency domain or time domain it really doesn't matter what the independent variable is (time, frequency, x, u etc). Convolution is convolution.